# When i'm trying to test rest-api is not working any methods all methods in postman is getting back and not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

Model Class

```
@Entity
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column
public String name;

@Column
public String lastName;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

}

--Repository

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>{
}
```

--Services

```
public interface PersonServices {

Person addPerson(Person person);

Person findOne(Long id);

List<Person> findAll();
}
```

-- THe class that implements Services Interface

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PersonServiesImpl implements PersonServices {

@Autowired
private PersonRepository personRepository;



@Override
@Transactional
public Person addPerson(Person person) {

    return personRepository.save(person);
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public Person findOne(Long id) {
    return personRepository.findOne(id);
}

@Override

public List<Person> findAll() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return personRepository.findAll();
}
}
```

The Controller Class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class PersonController {

@Autowired
private PersonServices personServices;



@RequestMapping(value = "/user",
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Person> savePerson(@RequestBody Person person){
    return new ResponseEntity<Person>(personServices.addPerson(person),HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/user",
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Person>> findAll(){
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Person>>(personServices.findAll(),HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}",
                method = RequestMethod.GET,
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Person> getFromId(@PathVariable("id")Long id){
    return new ResponseEntity<Person>(personServices.findOne(id),HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

}

--application.properties file

```
 spring.datasource.url =jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/managementsystem
 spring.datasource.username = root
 spring.datasource.password = root
 spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
 spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
 spring.profiles.active=dev
 server.port=8080
 server.sessionTimeout=30
 spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
 tomcat.accessLogEnabled=false
 tomcat.protocolHeader=x-forwarded-proto
 tomcat.remoteIpHeader=x-forwarded-for
 tomcat.backgroundProcessorDelay=30
```

The problem is that when i'm testing for example the method for saving one person at database the message that is returning in postman is {timestamp : 1242424 , message : not found , path:/rest/user . Can anyone help me , I'm beginner at Spring Boot Framework how to fix this ? I checked some tutorial but is almostly same like this i don't know . I hope that someone can help me :)

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the RestController and hence the controller method is not scanned. You should place the Starter class (the one annotated with @SpringBootApplication) above the controllers in folder hierarchy.

Comment: Yes i have the Starter class but i forget it to post here . The problem is not there because the application is started just the methods are not returning anything as i mention up . For ex : I'm testing the first method.POST to add some user but its not working .

Comment: It's not reaching the method. The controller method is not identified. The possible reason is that you might have added the Starter class in same hierarchical level of controller class(es). It has to be above the controller folders.

Comment: yes now i understand and the basepackage and hierarchical level wan't okay thanks you so much now it works :) Good bless you @Naveed S